# C#: Best way to achieve a nicely formatted time string?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, system.timers.timer

I am writing this question as I am asking for the best way to do this. I have many of these in my program and I want to make a method to convert a Int32 which contains a seconds of a timer into a nicely formatted string.

So for example, if my timer int was at lets say a random number like 16429
it would be:

```
4 hours, 32 minutes and 9 seconds
```

If it was 600, it would be:

```
10 minutes
```

If it was 60, it would be

```
1 minute
```

If it was 172801, it would be

```
2 days and 1 second
```

If it was 32, it would be

```
32 seconds
```

I want the "s" 's at the end of each word like "minute", "second" and "day" to only put S if it isn't equal to 1, therefor it isn't really needed to be pronounced correctly. I also only want days and hours and other things added if they are needed, so if the timer is below 1 day in seconds, it only shows hours, minutes and seconds, or what is needed.

What is the best way to achieve something like this? I have this function below, but it is very messy and only goes up to minutes and seconds, not hours or days:

```
public static string GetConvertedTime(int timer)
{
    int Minutes = timer / 60;
    int Seconds = timer - Minutes * 60;

    if (timer < 60)
    {
        string secs = (Seconds != 1) ? "s" : "";
        return "" + timer + " second" + secs;
    }

    else
    {
        if (Seconds < 1)
        {
            string mins = (Minutes != 1) ? "s" : "";
            return "" + Minutes + " minute" + mins;
        }
        else
        {
            string mins = (Minutes != 1) ? "s" : "";
            string secs = (Seconds != 1) ? "s" : "";
            return "" + Minutes + " minute" + mins + " and " + Seconds + " second" + secs;
        }
    }
}
```

What exactly is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

"Best way" is awfully subjective.  DRY is usually best, considering localization and non-regular pluralization forms is usually best, keeping it short and snappy is usually best:

```
public static string FriendlyDuration(int seconds) {
    int[] divisors = { 60 * 60 * 24, 60 * 60, 60 , 1};
    string[] language = { ", ", " and ", "days", "day", "hours", "hour", "minutes", "minute", "seconds", "second"};
    var parts = new List<string>();
    for (int part = 0; part < divisors.Length; ++part) {
        int count = seconds / divisors[part];
        if (count == 0) continue;
        string unit = language[part*2 + (count == 1 ? 3 : 2)];
        parts.Add(string.Format("{0} {1}", count, unit));
        seconds -= count * divisors[part];
    }
    var result = string.Join(language[0], parts.ToArray());
    if (parts.Count > 1) {
        var ix = result.LastIndexOf(language[0]);
        result = result.Substring(0, ix) + language[1] + result.Substring(ix + language[0].Length);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This looks like the kind of code I hope I'll think to write after another many years' experience, +1

Comment: Leave it to Hans Passant to write such an incredible example.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best way I can think of is to use a `TimeSpan` like so:

```
var time = new TimeSpan(0, 0, timer);
var s = "s";
return $"{time.Days} day{(time.Days != 1 ? s : String.Empty)}, {time.Hours} hour{(time.Hours != 1 ? s : String.Empty)}, {time.Minutes} minute{(time.Minutes != 1 ? s : String.Empty)}, and {time.Seconds} second{(time.Seconds != 1 ? s : String.Empty)}";
```

if you need to hide the empty leading values:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var s = "s";
var time = new TimeSpan(0, 0, timer);
var continuation = false;
if (time.Days > 0)
{
    sb.Append($"{time.Days} day{(time.Days != 1 ? s : String.Empty)}, ");
    continuation = true;
}
if (time.Hours > 0 || continuation)
{
    sb.Append($"{time.Hours} hour{(time.Hours != 1 ? s : String.Empty)}, ");
    continuation = true;
}
if (time.Minutes > 0 || continuation)
{
    sb.Append($"{time.Minutes} minute{(time.Minutes != 1 ? s : String.Empty)}{(continuation ? "," : String.Empty)} ");
    continuation = true;
}
if (continuation) sb.Append("and ");

sb.Append($"{time.Seconds} second{(time.Seconds != 1 ? s : String.Empty)}");
return sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this library named [Humanizer](https://github.com/Humanizr/Humanizer)

Comment: Link-only answers aren't very useful

Comment: @Buhbuh, sure they are, what would you expect to be in the answer, the complete source code from github? Knowing that the product exists is v useful, having a link to it is even better

Comment: @pm100 I think a reasonable expectation would be to show how to accomplish the task using said library. "Try this library" is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: @pm100 and yet under [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) we have a section just for these type of answers. _Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline._