# Possible to Add words "minutes" or "seconds" with DateFormat?

Tags: c#, timespan

I have something like this

```
   var diff = endDate.Value.Subtract(DateTime.UtcNow); // gives a timespan
   var msg = diff.ToString("locked out for another mm minutes and ss seconds");
```

Was hoping that it would be able to parse out `mm` and `ss` and replace it with the correct values but I am getting an exception.

Edit

I guess I can do it like this

```
"Locked out for another {diff.Minutes} minutes and {diff.Seconds} seconds"
```

but still curious if it can be done all in the `toString()`

Comment: It can be done by quoting your custom text. However, your second approach is better and you should probably use `(int)diff.TotalMinutes` instead of just `diff.Minutes` in case the timespan is more than 60 minutes, e.g. if diff is 2 hours `mm` and `diff.Minutes` would just return 0 (because 2 hours and 0 minutes), but `(int)diff.TotalMinutes` would return 120.

Comment: so your casting it to an int to drop off the I guess the seconds portion which would be covered by the seconds portion?

Comment: Yes, it’s to ignore the seconds, milliseconds and so on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42632169/c-best-way-to-achieve-a-nicely-formatted-time-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way

```
diff.ToString("'Locked out for another 'mm' minutes and 'ss' seconds'")
```

for more info see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings)

Answer (score 0):

The ToString method for a TimeSpan can take a format string, but it requires special formatting.

```
var diff = endDate.Value.Subtract(DateTime.UtcNow);
// If our TimeSpan value is 1h, 2m, 3s, this would print 1:2:3
var msg = diff.ToString(@"hh\:mm\:ss")
```

To print a message like what you're looking for I would just use regular string formatting.

```
var msg = String.Format("locked out for another {0:%m} minutes and {0:%s} seconds", diff)
```

In this example, {0:%m} is saying I want %m value of the format argument 0, or the first argument after the format string. And {0:%s} says I want the %s value for argument 0. The formatting values for a TimeSpan can be found here.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings